# Google cloud platform - ML engine - Flower dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, image-recognition, google-cloud-ml

Getting below error on pre-processing of evaluation data.

Command that I am running -

```
python trainer/preprocess.py \
    --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
    --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv" \
    --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval" \
    --cloud
```

**Error**

```
 File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 490, in <module>main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 486, in main run(arg_dict)
  File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 393, in run with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
  File "/home/ankitagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 131, in __init__
    'Pipeline has validations errors: \n' + '\n'.join(errors))
ValueError: Pipeline has validations errors:
Invalid GCS bucket (gs:// ml-flowers-216007/ankitagupta/flowers_ankitagupta_20180910_144047/preproc/temp), given for the option: temp_location. See https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/bucketnaming for more details.
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this address. There is a space in this address(after `gs://` part), find where it comes from and remove it:

```
gs:// ml-flowers-216007/ankitagupta/flowers_ankitagupta_20180910_144047/preproc/temp
```